# How to hide/disable close button or at least catch/override built-in quit() function? (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.4, quit

I need to do some actions before quit (save settings, etc.), I do it with Button widgets, but if I press on close button of the window, it just closes. Maybe I should handle App's `on_close()` event somehow? Then I don't know how to send data from Layout to App. For now I have smth like:

```
def quit_game(self):
        # Saving different data.
        ...
        quit()
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should [handle the `on_stop` method on your `App` class](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#profiling-with-on-start-and-on-stop) by implementing the appropriate method.

Example:

```
class MyApp(App):
    ...
    def on_stop(self):
        # do what you need to here
        value_to_save = self.root.subwidget.value
        # self.root is your root widget - either the 
        # widget you return from App.build() or
        # the root widget in your app kv file
```

Keep in mind, also, that if you plan to develop for Android you will need to implement `on_pause` as well. After an Android app is paused, it can be killed without warning by the OS and your `on_stop` method will not be called.

Comment: It seems it works now, but some issue. I have string `on_release: app.stop()` in *.kv, so this string calls `on_stop()` twice, what do I wrong? And what should I type in `on_pause()`? The same as in `on_stop()`?

Comment: I would suggest doing all of your saving in a new method (i.e. `save_game()` or similar) and call that method from both `on_pause()` and `on_stop()`.

Comment: I thought so. What about double call?

Comment: The `on_stop` being dispatched twice is a bug in Kivy. You can work around this for now by using `stopTouchApp()` with a kv import. I submitted this bug with a workaround here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2397